# How to restrict Google Maps API AutocompleteService from giving out of bounds suggestions

Tags: java, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Currently I'm working with `AutocompleteService` class from the Google Maps API. From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-autocomplete-service) I'm using the `bounds` to apply the bounds for New York City. However, I'm getting results from NJ and PA.

There is no `strictBounds` option for the AutocompleteService class and this makes it hard to restrict results to only be within bounds. Here are the following bounds I'm providing for NYC:

```
/**
 * NYC Bound Parameters for Google Maps API
 * @enum {object}
 */
 OfficeMap.NYC_BOUNDS = {
   'south': 40.4773991,
   'west': -74.25908989999999,
   'north': 40.9175771,
   'east': -73.7002721
 };
```

However, this is not completely working as expected since suggestions from outside New York have been showing:
[image]

As you see from the image above suggestions from PA are shown.

```
  /** @private {this._google.maps.places.Autocomplete}Autocomplete instance */
    this._service = new this._google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();

  // Attach handler for the autocomplete search box. This updates the map
    // position and re-sorts locations around that position.
    this._searchEl.addEventListener('keyup', event => {
      if(event.target.value) {
        this._service.getPlacePredictions({
           input: event.target.value,
           offset: 3,
           types: ['geocode'],
           componentRestrictions: {country: 'us'},
           bounds: OfficeMap.NYC_BOUNDS
        }, predictions => {
          if(predictions) {
            let results = predictions.map(e => [e['description']]);
            this._inputAutocomplete._autocomplete.options = results;
            const autocompleteSelf = this._inputAutocomplete._autocomplete;

            this._inputAutocomplete._autocomplete.select = () => {
                if (autocompleteSelf.highlightedIndex !== -1) {
                  autocompleteSelf.input.value = autocompleteSelf
                    .scoredOptions[autocompleteSelf.highlightedIndex]
                    .displayValue;
                  autocompleteSelf.removeDropdown();

                  let nameOfLocation = autocompleteSelf.input.value;
                  let googlePlaceObj = this.getGooglePlaceByName(nameOfLocation,
                                                                 predictions);

                  this.displayPlacesOnMap(googlePlaceObj);
                }
              };
            }
        });
      }
    });
```

The method `getPlacePredictions` should only give out NYC suggestions since is NYC bounds parameter which are passed. From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-autocomplete-service#AutocompleteService.getPlacePredictions)
there is no way to restrict it.

How can I restrict to AutocompleteService `getPlacePredictions` to only return objects within bounds?

Comment: While annoying, [the documentation you linked to](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-autocomplete-service#AutocompletionRequest) for the `bounds` does say "Predictions will be biased towards, but not restricted to, the given bounds."

Answer (score 0):

Especially since the `AutocompleteService` is `@private`, it seems like you should be using the [`Autocomplete`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#add_autocomplete) class instead, which does support `strictBounds`.

Comment: The problem is that `Autocomplete` doesn't provide the `offset` option which I need.

Comment: Have you tried passing in the needed option to one or the other? Possible it's supported even though it's not documented, since I bet `Autocomplete` is just passing to `AutocompleteService` under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

We have an entry for this feature request to add **strictBounds for Autocomplete Service** in our Google Public Issue Tracker.

Issues in the Issue Tracker are directly curated by Google Maps Platform API specialists, who will provide updates in the Issue Tracker whenever there's news from the engineering team.

We would like to warmly invite you to view the issue in the Issue Tracker, and to star it to register your interest. This will subscribe you to receive technical updates on the issue. Starring the issue also provides us with valuable feedback on the importance of the issue to our customers, and increases the issue's priority with the product engineering team.

You can view and star the issue here:
- https://issuetracker.google.com/36219203

This Issue Tracker entry is the authoritative source for public information regarding this issue, and all publicly-relevant updates will be posted there.

Answer (score 0):

bit late but if you are someone still looking for a solution as I was ¯_(ツ)_/¯

bounds, location, and radius are deprecated on May 2023 instead we can use **locationBias** and **locationRestriction** refer to this link

Documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-autocomplete-service#AutocompletionRequest.locationRestriction

Worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).